# JPA Referencing Multiple column to same table

Tags: java, micronaut

For e.g.
I have a event table which reference to user table

productionmanager--->user

organiser--->user

presenter-->user

but I am getting error
JPA/Hibernate Multiple representations of the same entity

I need to do create and update both operations

Please guide me I am new to JAVA using it with mirconaut.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.